# SQL sort column A & update column B

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting

I have a table with data similar to:

```
Inven    DESCRIPT     PrintOrder
---------------------------------
1        D             9
2        B             0
3        A             5
4        Z             0
5        X             1
.        .             .
.        .             .
.        .             .
```

I would like to sort the table on column DESCRIPT descending alpha (A - Z) and then update the column PRINTORDER so that when done, the record with PRINTORDER = 1 is the the highest alpha (A) and the record with the highest value for PRINTORDER will be the lowest in alpha (Z).

Is this possible without using temporary columns?  Not a deal breaker if not, just a preference.

DESIRED RESULT:

To update the PrintOrder values based on the sorting result

```
Inven    DESCRIPT     PrintOrder
---------------------------------
1        D             3
2        B             2
3        A             1
4        Z             5
5        X             4
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and provide desired output?  Also, tag your question with the database you are using.  Also, do you just want a result set or do you want to modify the data in the database?

Comment: I have added an example result.  It is MySQL. - Thanks

Comment: Will test at office tomorrow and select answer.  Thanks for every ones help!

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
Update T
set PRINTORDER = ASCII(UPPER(DESCRIPT)) - 64
```

while the ASCII of A is 65 in your system. :)

EDIT:

As you said there might be something more, so we need to change it a bit by assuming you have a PK column name as Id:

```
UPDATE T
set PRINTORDER = T2.Order
FROM T
     INNER JOIN (SELECT IDENTITY(int, 1,1) AS Order,Id FROM T Order By DESCRIPT ASC) T2 ON T.Id=T2.Id
```

But in this way even two record has same DESCRIPT would end up have different printorder, it could be a bit more complex if you want keep them the same.

EDIT:
Sorry just realized you are using MySql, the IDENTITY(int, 1,1) is from SQL Server, basically it generate a row number, you might need something different to have one: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2014/03/08/mysql-generating-row-number-for-each-row-using-variable/

Comment: There will be INT values as well as special characters (0-9  $ % etc).  Does this fact change your answer?  Like  -32  or something to include more ?  (I only listed it as A-Z for illustrative purposes)

Comment: Or is it dependent on what char set is defined for the DB ?

Comment: hmm, I thought you only have A-Z there, in that case it really depends on how you want to order those values, ASCII should be accurate for order them as long as only one char involved. But if you have special characters they might have a lower ASCII number then A can't start from . I was joking about ASCII, all system has the same value for those standard chars, shouldn't need to worry if it's different

Answer (score 0):

I am unclear whether you want to *modify* the table or just create a result set.  Here is the solution to the latter using standard SQL:

```
select Inven, Descript, row_number() over (order by Descript) as PrintOrder
from table t
order by Descript;
```

EDIT:

In MySQL, the `select` would look like:

```
select t.*
from (select Inven, Descript, (@rn := @rn + 1) as PrintOrder
      from table t cross join (select @rn := 0) params
      order by Descript
     ) t
order by Inven;
```

The `update` is slightly trickier, because you cannot sort *and* initialize a variable:

```
update t
    set PrintOrder = (@rn := coalesce(@rn + 1, 1))
    order by Descript;
```

Answer (score 0):

After arriving at my office, and chatting with my colleague, the question posed is completely inaccurate. So I'll close this thread, and an open a new one with a more accurate description of the issue.

Thank you Gordon & Simon for your responses, they are most appreciated.